# php get last word from many sentences in a .txt document

Tags: php, file

I have found many partly answers already on stack overflow but i don't get the pieces properly together. This because i am a php beginner.

What i have working:

- Write short sentences line per line from a textfield in data.txt.
- read every sentences line per line from data.txt

What i want to get working:

- read one sentences per one from data.txt

and

- get last word from every sentences line per line from data.txt

The code to read that doesn't work:

```
 <?php
$last_word = array();

$handle = @fopen("data.txt", "r");
if ($handle)
{
    while (!feof($handle))
    {
        $buffer = fgets($handle);
        $last_word_start = strpos($buffer, ' ') + 1; 
        $last_word = substr($buffer, $last_word_start);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

//show results:
print_r($last_word);
?>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Missing `[]` It would be  `$last_word[]=substr..`

Comment: With `strrpos` you'll get last space position

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays and explode:

```
$str = " bla bla bla bla 1
bla bla bla bla blab la bla 2
bla bla bla bla blab la bla esef 3
bla bla bla bla blab la bla asd4";

$array = explode("\n", $str);

foreach($array as $value){
    $temp  = explode(" ", $value);
    $lastword[] = end($temp);
}

var_dump($lastword);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cc1280f8f8af1f1a19ced0b9c732328ab75ec178